# mysql query suggestions

Tags: mysql

i have some doubt about my mysql query and wanted to discuss here.
i have three tables tablea,tableb and tablec

```
 tablea 

id    someid
1       434
2       352
3       329
```

tableb

```
id     otherid     cid
1      434         54        
2      6934         2453
3      434         24
4      9548        67
```

here  otherid is appearing more than one time and also appearing once in tablea

tablec

```
id       otherid     cid  
1        all deleted row details of tableb will be stored here
```

what i am doing

selecting one random row from tablec and matching someid with otherid
and as i want to store the tableb details in tablec so first i am performing insert into for tablec and then deleting the tableb row
it seems to be correct but in tableb more than one rows are there so deleting is not an issue as i can directly match with someid and delete all rows from tableb but in tablec i have to insert the cid values also so if i will do as ihave explained it will work fine ?any suggestions are welcome

Comment: have you looked into any database triggers?

Comment: @DRapp no i have bot checked

Comment: Could you try rephrasing the question a bit? I sincerely dont understand what you're asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson from tablec i have one id which i am searching in tableb and when i find that id in tableb i will be interested in inserting tableb values in tablec and then delete that row from tableb

Comment: Don't do this.  See [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @eggyal nothing is comma seperated.everything is in different column

Comment: Erm.  Okay.  Could you explain `tablec.cid` a little better, then?  It appeared to me from your question that that was a single column that contained all of the `cid` from `tableb` having the same `otherid`?

Comment: @eggyal its like friendship. cid is users id who has requested you to become your friend

Comment: @eggyal 100% correct but not to mehe can request to any other usrrs